# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax (...) near ''

Tags: mysql, sql

Running this sql query in mysql:

```
INSERT INTO Test_id_isbnyear    
  SELECT I.id, I.isbn, Y.year    
  FROM Prod_id_isbn AS I     
  LEFT JOIN Prod_id_year AS Y  ;
```

Throw this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax (...) near '' at line 4

How can I get an error about a '"' if there is no such thing in my query?

Comment: Doesn't that `JOIN` need an `ON` clause?

Comment: Omg David, thank you so much - you saved me a couple of grey hairs. Also, I'm somewhat ashamed right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly the error message isn't *super* helpful in this case.  There may be exceptions to the rule, but in my experience this *usually* means that the syntax error is at the very end of the query.  Which, in this case, it is:

```
SELECT I.id, I.isbn, Y.year    
FROM Prod_id_isbn AS I     
LEFT JOIN Prod_id_year AS Y
-- missing "ON" clause
```

Should be something like:

```
SELECT I.id, I.isbn, Y.year    
FROM Prod_id_isbn AS I     
LEFT JOIN Prod_id_year AS Y
  ON I.SomeField = Y.SomeField
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join your values on something (I  have assumed `ON I.ID = Y.I_ID` for this answer).

```
INSERT INTO Test_id_isbnyear    
SELECT I.id, I.isbn, Y.year    
FROM Prod_id_isbn I     
LEFT JOIN Prod_id_year Y ON I.ID = Y.I_ID;
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you very much for your answer. I was confused by the error message and looking in the wrong direction for a solution.